# Pandas merging connected groups from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I group rows which have at least one value in common? I can pass multiple columns to `groupby` but I want any one of them to be considered, not all of them.

Sample code:

```py
import pandas as pd

input = pd.DataFrame({
  'fruit': ['peach', 'banana', pd.NA, 'peach', 'apple', 'avocado', pd.NA],
  'vegetable': [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'zucchini', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'potato'],
  'sugar': [17, 17, 2, 18, 20, pd.NA, 4],
  'color': ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'brown']
})

output = input.groupby(['fruit', 'vegetable', 'sugar', 'color']).agg({
  'fruit': lambda x: list(set(x)),
  'vegetable': lambda x: list(set(x)),
  'sugar': lambda x: list(set(x)),
  'color': lambda x: list(set(x))
})
```

Input:

```
    fruit       vegetable   sugar   color
0   peach                   17      orange
1   banana                  17      yellow
2               zucchini    2       green
3   peach                   18      orange
4   apple                   20      red
5   avocado                         green
6               potato      4       brown
```

Expected output:

```
    fruit               vegetable   sugar       color
0   [peach, banana]     []          [17, 18]    [orange, yellow]
1   [avocado]           [zucchini]  [2]         [green]
2   [apple]             []          [20]        [red]
3   []                  [potato]    [4]         [brown]
```

Comment: May I know the logic between the input and the expected output? Because after comparing these two I am not able to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Rows with at least one value (column) in common are merged, and their values are grouped into lists.

Comment: but there could be a match on different caterogies, should it merge groups? For example, what should happen if `yellow` and `red` were `green`?  That seems like an ambiguous problem ;) Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You may try by having the all values of each row in a list and then using the intersection check if there are any common elements and then merge it.

Comment: Yes it seems weird because of the simplistic example :) If `yellow` and `red` were `green` then yes they would be merged. In the end I'm trying to get a contingency table to feed to an upset plot. This is the step I'm struggling with...

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to check list intersections with pandas?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a "straightforward" way in pandas.

Comment: @StrangePotato you can use `networkx`. I provided a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71048227/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem seems to be a graph problem.

###### finding the groups per column

First, lets see which rows are grouped per column

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
groups = {col:
          list(chain.from_iterable(list(combinations(x, 2))
                                   for x in df.index.groupby(df[col]).values()
                                   if len(x)>1))
          for col in df.columns}

# {'fruit': [(0, 3)],
#  'vegetable': [],
#  'sugar': [(0, 1)],
#  'color': [(2, 5), (0, 3)]}
```

So, here we would like to merge the groups (0,3) and (0,1) as 0 is common.

###### getting the connected components

Let's use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
import networkx as nx

edges = list(chain.from_iterable(groups.values()))

G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)
G.add_nodes_from(df.index)

combined_groups = {k:v for v,l in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))
                   for k in l}
# index: group_id
# {0: 0, 1: 0, 3: 0, 2: 1, 5: 1, 4: 2, 6: 3}
```

[image]

###### final groupby

```
df.groupby(df.index.map(combined_groups)).agg(list)
```

output:

```
                    fruit           vegetable         sugar                     color
0  [peach, banana, peach]  [<NA>, <NA>, <NA>]  [17, 17, 18]  [orange, yellow, orange]
1         [<NA>, avocado]    [zucchini, <NA>]     [2, <NA>]            [green, green]
2                 [apple]              [<NA>]          [20]                     [red]
3                  [<NA>]            [potato]           [4]                   [brown]
```

Comment: May I know why you provided solution using `networkx` when user is looking for solution in `pandas`?

Comment: @TonyMontana **this is a pandas solution**, just with help of `networkx` to form the groups. I don't think you can do this just with `pandas`, but I'd be happy to vote for any decent solution that proves me wrong ;)

Comment: @mozway This is great and ingenious! Thanks for introducing me to `networkx`. I had tunnel vision trying to solve this solely with `pandas`.

Comment: Well, in theory you could write your own grouping function (e.g., using `set` intersection), but this wouldn't be pure pandas in any case. `networkx` is really making things easy ;)

Comment: Hey @mozway, kindly check my answer using `pandas` only. I know it's not the best way to do, but I like to do it the hard way anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After a "challenge" by the @mozway, I tried to give a chance and this is my "Hard way" attempt on the above mentioned problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit': ['peach', 'banana', pd.NA, 'peach', 'apple', 'avocado', pd.NA],
    'vegetable': [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'zucchini', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'potato'],
    'sugar': [17, 17, 2, 18, 20, pd.NA, 4],
    'color': ['orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'brown']
})

# Replacing pd.NA with empty string
df.replace(pd.NA, '', inplace=True)

# Initializing output dataframe with the columns of input dataframe
output_df = df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df.columns)

# Converting all the values per each row to list and removing empty values from it
df['common'] = df.values.tolist()
df['common'] = df['common'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(lambda y: y != '', x)))

check_list = set()
index = 0

# Iterating over each row of df
for i, row_i in df.iterrows():
    # Check if the index of row_i is not in check_list
    if i not in check_list:
        # Looping through the columns and setting up the output_df with each value as a list
        for column in df.columns[:-1]:
            temp = str(df.at[i, column])
            output_df.at[index, column] = [temp] if temp else []
        # Looping throught the dataframe again to compare the 'common' values
        for j, row_j in df.iterrows():
            # Check if index of row_j is not in check_list and not matches with the index of row_i
            if i != j and j not in check_list:
                # Check the common values between row_i and row_j
                # if found, update the output_df and append the values into the already defined list
                if set(row_i['common']).intersection(row_j['common']):
                    for column in df.columns[:-1]:
                        temp = str(df.at[j, column])
                        # Avoid the duplicate values in the column
                        if temp and temp not in output_df.at[index, column]:
                            output_df.at[index, column].append(temp)
                    check_list.add(j)
        # Increment the index of output_df
        index += 1

print(output_df)
```

And this is the output, I am getting:

```
             fruit   vegetable     sugar             color
0  [peach, banana]          []  [17, 18]  [orange, yellow]
1        [avocado]  [zucchini]       [2]           [green]
2          [apple]          []      [20]             [red]
3               []    [potato]       [4]           [brown]
```

But anyway, the answer give my @mozway is subtle, easy and short.

Comment: I have to say, I gave it a try with a `set` approach. Using a dozen of lines I had a nice approach until I realized that merging groups is actually a complex task. For instance if you have `{1,2}` then `{3,4}`, they are distinct, but if later a `{2,3}` is seen this means you would need to come back and merge them. So the task is not as simple as it seems… I haven't studied your code in detail, but I'd say there is a non negligible chance of a flaw somewhere so I'd rather stick to a proven approach :p That said, I'll give you an upvote for the attempt ;)

Comment: @mozway Yeah, there might be a chance of flaw, because I haven't tested it on all possible scenarios. I just wanted to give a try that's it. I am not asking you to accept my solution at all. I just wanted to prove that this can be possible using pandas as well

Comment: IMO this does not constitute a proof. This produces the expected output on a single dataset ;) You would need to test more tricky examples such as I described.

Comment: @mozway, well you may test it by yourself or you may provide me the tricky examples as well. The one you described in earlier comment, I didn't get it. Can you be more specific, is possible?

Comment: sure ;) fails on this example: `pd.DataFrame({'fruit':['peach','banana',nan,'peach',nan,'apple','avocado',nan,'peach'],'vegetable':[nan,nan,'zucchini',nan,nan,nan,nan,'potato',nan],'sugar':[17.0,17.0,2.0,18.0,19.0,20.0,nan,4.0,10.0],'color':['orange','yellow','green','orange','blue','red','green','brown','blue']})`

Comment: @mozway yeah, you are right. Even with the modification on the approach I took, it would not be an efficient one. Let me repost this as a new question with the scenario you mentioned but the solutions using only `pandas`. Thanks anyway.